# Third party dependency :- Invalid hook call warning

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am getting stuck at invalid hook warning. It is a third party dependency which makes it hard to control as well. But here is a code which causing the issue,

```
export class Component {
    constructor() {
        this._initReact();
    }
    _initReact(displayName) {
        const component = React.forwardRef((props = {}, ref) => {
            const _a = Object.assign(Object.assign({}, this._props), props), { className, container, label, title, tag = 'div' } = _a, styleProps = __rest(_a, ["className", "container", "label", "title", "tag"]);
            // set up component state via useState hook
            const [, setId] = React.useState(this._uuid);
            // subscribe to svg replacement via useEffect hook
            React.useEffect(() => {
                const onSvgReplaced = () => {
                    setId(this._uuid);
                };
                this._svgReplaced.connect(onSvgReplaced);
                // specify cleanup callback as hook return
                return () => {
                    this._svgReplaced.disconnect(onSvgReplaced);
                };
            });
            // make it so that tag can be used as a jsx component
            const Tag = tag;
            // ensure that svg html is valid
            if (!(this.svgInnerHTML && this.svgReactAttrs)) {
                // bail if failing silently
                return React.createElement(React.Fragment, null);
            }
            const svgComponent = (React.createElement("svg", Object.assign({}, this.svgReactAttrs, { dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: this.svgInnerHTML }, ref: ref })));
            if (container) {
                Private.initContainer({ container, className, styleProps, title });
                return (React.createElement(React.Fragment, null,
                    svgComponent,
                    label));
            }
            else {
                return (React.createElement(Tag, { className: classes(className, LabIconStyle.styleClass(styleProps)) },
                    svgComponent,
                    label));
            }
        });
        component.displayName = `LabIcon_${displayName}`;
        return component;
    }
}
```

In this function useState and useEffect is where the warnings are coming from ?
Any suggestions to get past to this will be a great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the `LabIcon` component, yeah? https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/master/packages/ui-components/src/icon/labicon.tsx#L454

That's a class component, but `useEffect` and `useState` hooks can only be used in function components and in other hooks: https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

> You can only call Hooks while React is rendering a function component:
>
> Call them at the top level in the body of a function component.
>
> Call them at the top level in the body of a custom Hook.

Comment: That's how the jupyter lab team has wrote this component, when they run this component, it works for them but it's not working for me. Do you have any suggestion how I can fix this ? I even tried change LabIcon component to functional component locally. That didn't change the outcome, still the same problem `Invalid hook call. `

Comment: I'm not sure how to get rid of it, no. I imagine they don't see the warning because they're using a different version of React, or they have a configuration setting that ignores that particular warning.

Comment: Just confirmed that the react version is same, what baffles me is even converting this component to functional component also has the same behavior.
Also another point is I am modifying the compiled files for changing it to functional component, so not everything is accurate there

Comment: Issue was there were multiple react app running.